# How to find an arbitrarily oriented minimum bounding box in c++

Tags: c++, geometry

So let's say I have a list of N pairs of positive long coordinates (points).
How do I find the smallest rectangle containing all of them?
The rectangle can also have floating coordinates and be rotated in any angle and further shrunk... Not just X, Y, Width and Height!

[image: Just an image I found on the web...]

I already know how to find the smallest polygon or not rotated rectangle, but it's not what I need...I wish to know how to find the arbitrarily oriented minimum bounding box.

Comment: "Vector composing algorithm" sounds like something out of CSI:Miami :P

Comment: Wow. It'd be nice, but I don't think they will find any practical use for mine...

Comment: [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1487) had a similar, though not exactly the same, question you might be able to adapt.

Comment: @kojiro No, it's not even close to what I need.

Comment: @Vercas: How "perfect" does it have to be? Is "close to optimal" ok?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See http://www.geometrictools.com/Source/ComputationalGeometry.html

The section "Minimum-area box" has various examples.

e.g.

> Compute a minimum-area oriented box containing the specified points.
> The algorithm uses the rotating callipers method.

https://www.geometrictools.com/Samples/Geometrics.html#MinimumAreaBox2D

https://www.geometrictools.com/GTE/Mathematics/MinimumAreaBox2.h

Comment: Thank you! That file contains just the function I need! I also found more things that I need on that site!

Comment: I knew it did as I used it this morning myself. Half the battle in finding something is knowing the correct terms!

Comment: Well I understood enough to know what you meant...even if google didn't ;)

Comment: From the description, this doesn't appear accurate.  A true minimum area box would most likely have a center that was _not_ the average of the points.  They seem to be using a shortcut to simply get something pretty close.

Comment: @Vercas: this does not compute the minimum box. The correct answer is given by "rotating calipers". http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/rotcal.html

Comment: The original link did, so I have rolled back the answer even though now it 404s.

Answer (score 10):

This [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms) notes that you can solve this problem by using the fact that the minimum rectangle must have an edge collinear with one of the edges of the convex hull.

Comment: That Wikipedia page does not contain an algorithm; the "rotating calipers" page it links to does contain an algorithm, but not for this problem. Some actual links: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/maer.html, http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#WMkTvnMDpLM/cv/src/cvrotcalipers.cpp&q=cvMinAreaRect2. Note that this approach works for any reasonable definition of "minimum"; in particular it works for "minimum area" and "minimum perimeter"; these two often coincide but not always.

Comment: Thanks Gareth (and hi!) I've changed the wording of my answer.

Comment: For each line-segment in the convex hull, you can calculate the area of the bounding rectangle using it, and choose the smallest. It runs O(n^2) in the number of points on the hull though.

Comment: Hi, Paul. I thought it was probably the same Paul Hankin :-). Thomas, it actually turns out to be O(n) once you've got the convex hull, if you do it right. See, e.g., the first link in my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this paper can help: [Smallest k point enclosing rectangle of arbitrary orientation](http://www.cccg.ca/proceedings/2004/29.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: This paper addresses the harder problem of finding a bounding *square*. As you can see, the complexity is O(N²Log(N)), whereas the bounding rectangle is easily obtained in O(N Log(N)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be of help to you, but here's my thoughts on how I'd approach the problem.

You'll need functions to find your "corner-most" points (in your example, the left 2 and right 2 points). Given those 4 points, connect them with lines.

(Note in your example image, the top point would not be contained by the generated rectangle, so...)
You'll then need a function to determine if the rectangle generated contains all given points; if not, extend the endpoints (in this case, the top 2 points of the generated rectangle) by N (which is either a single measure ... say a pixel, or if you're smart, the distance to the point that's out of bounds plus/minus one dependant on the direction) and re-evaluate.

Comment: Good point; in that case, you'd need to derive the function (y=mx+b) representing the connection between the two points, and continue along that path -- along both sides of your original rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

### Maybe this works for you:

- find the center point of all your points (sum of all x / number of x's, same for y)
- take the farthest point from the center as a corner point
- project line through the 2nd farthest point in a 90° angle of the corner point
- iterate over the points of the other side of the center point and find minimum

Comment: Step #3 and #4 is super confusing and make no sense to me