# Finding an oriented bounding box for a set of 3D points in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I have a set of 3D points, or in fact small spheres, that I need to enclose with the smallest possible 3D box using Unity 3D.

In the case where the enclosing box can only be moved and scaled, the solution is quite trivial, you simply iterate over all the points and encapsulate each one. But I also need to find the best possible orientation for the box.

So, to illustrate the problem in ASCII, given a basic 2D scenario with only two points:

```
Y
| * (0,1)
|
|
|
|               * (1,0)
-------------------- X
```

Using a regular growing bounding box, you will end up with a very large enclosing box containing mostly blank space, while in this case I need a box that is very thin and rotated about 45 degrees around the Z axis. Basically just a line connecting the two points.

I never know how many points that needs to be grouped together though. And as mentioned, it has to work in 3D.

So far I only tried the basic approach where I do not rotate the encapsulating box for the best fit. The result is really way off what I need.

I was considering a brute force method, based on genetic algorithms, where I generate huge amounts of random boxes and simply select the one with the lowest area while still containing all the points. However, that is too slow.

```
GameObject go = points[0];
Bounds b = new Bounds(go.transform.position,go.transform.localScale);

for (int i=1;i<points.Count;i++)
{
    go = points[i];
    b.Encapsulate(new Bounds(go.transform.position, go.transform.localScale));
}

GameObject containingBox = Instantiate(boxPrefab);
containingBox.transform.position = b.center;
containingBox.transform.localScale = b.size;
containingBox.transform.rotation= Quaternion.Identity; //How to calculate?
```

Comment: This is an interesting question but it may be too broad as to be off topic for stack overflow. If you can break it down into smaller problems we may be able to help you.

Comment: This wikipedia article may help you: [Minimum bounding box algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms)

Comment: Yeah what you are asking for is actually quite comlicated to impement. Search for `Joseph O'Rourke minimal volume algorithm` .. some alternatives are e.g. mentioned [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a08-_containers.html)

Comment: Oh and [here](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MinimumVolumeBox.pdf) is a quit "new" short paper which provides pretty awesome pseudo code you basically only have to grab and convert into a Unity c# code or even take their [entire implementation](https://www.geometrictools.com/GTEngine/Include/Mathematics/GteMinimumVolumeBox3.h) and convert it to c# (careful with copyrights though)

Comment: You might be also very interested in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/wiki-howto-oriented-bounding-box-in-unity-finally-eek.610240/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey I searched around a bit and I found a pretty powerful library which offers what you are looking for more or less straight forward and even actively supports Unity types:

**[geometry3Sharp](https://github.com/gradientspace/geometry3Sharp)**

The implementation into a Unity Project is as simple as

- Download the project as `.zip`
- unpack the folder `geometry3Sharp-master` into your `Assets` folder
- In Unity under `ProjectSettings` → `Player` → `Other Settings` → `Configuration` → `Scripting Define Symbols` insert

  ```
  G3_USING_UNITY;
  ```

  Just as also explained in the README:

  > `geometry3Sharp` supports transparent conversion with Unity types. To enable this, define `G3_USING_UNITY` in your Unity project, by adding this string to the Scripting Define Symbols box in the Player Settings.

Then you can simply calculate the edges of an oriented bounding box for a given array of `Vector3` points like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using g3;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Just for the demo I used Transforms so I can simply move them around in the scene
    public Transform[] transforms;

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // First wehave to convert the Unity Vector3 array
        // into the g3 type g3.Vector3d
        var points3d = new Vector3d[transforms.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < transforms.Length; i++)
        {
            // Thanks to the g3 library implictely casted from UnityEngine.Vector3 to g3.Vector3d
            points3d[i] = transforms[i].position;
        }

        // BOOM MAGIC!!!
        var orientedBoundingBox = new ContOrientedBox3(points3d);

        // Now just convert the information back to Unity Vector3 positions and axis
        // Since g3.Vector3d uses doubles but Unity Vector3 uses floats
        // we have to explicitly cast to Vector3
        var center = (Vector3)orientedBoundingBox.Box.Center;

        var axisX = (Vector3)orientedBoundingBox.Box.AxisX;
        var axisY = (Vector3)orientedBoundingBox.Box.AxisY;
        var axisZ = (Vector3)orientedBoundingBox.Box.AxisZ;
        var extends = (Vector3)orientedBoundingBox.Box.Extent;

        // Now we can simply calculate our 8 vertices of the bounding box
        var A = center - extends.z * axisZ - extends.x * axisX - axisY * extends.y;
        var B = center - extends.z * axisZ + extends.x * axisX - axisY * extends.y;
        var C = center - extends.z * axisZ + extends.x * axisX + axisY * extends.y;
        var D = center - extends.z * axisZ - extends.x * axisX + axisY * extends.y;

        var E = center + extends.z * axisZ - extends.x * axisX - axisY * extends.y;
        var F = center + extends.z * axisZ + extends.x * axisX - axisY * extends.y;
        var G = center + extends.z * axisZ + extends.x * axisX + axisY * extends.y;
        var H = center + extends.z * axisZ - extends.x * axisX + axisY * extends.y;

        // And finally visualize it
        Gizmos.DrawLine(A, B);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(B, C);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(C, D);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(D, A);

        Gizmos.DrawLine(E, F);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(F, G);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(G, H);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(H, E);

        Gizmos.DrawLine(A, E);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(B, F);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(D, H);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(C, G);

        // And Here we ca just be amazed ;)
    }
}
```

[image]

---

And of course there is stuff like

```
orientedBoundingBox.Box.Contains(Vector3d)
```

for determine if a given point lies within that box.

---

Just because Ruzihm asked:

Ofcourse you can slightly change the upper script to simply use actual mesh vertices:

```
public MeshFilter[] meshFilters;

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    var vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    foreach (var meshFilter in meshFilters)
    {
        // have to multiply the vertices' positions
        // with the lossyScale and add it to the transform.position 
        vertices.AddRange(meshFilter.sharedMesh.vertices.Select(vertex => meshFilter.transform.position + Vector3.Scale(vertex, meshFilter.transform.lossyScale)));
    }

    var points3d = new Vector3d[vertices.Count];

    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
    {
        points3d[i] = vertices[i];
    }

    // ...
    // From here the code is the same as above
```

Which looks basically the same

[image]

Comment: Oh hey that's nice. Good find

Comment: So in order to make this work with spheres, you could put some points on the surface of each sphere and take all the points from all the spheres and put them in?

Comment: @Ruzihm either that or alternatively for an aproximation you can get the `orientedBoundingBox` for each sphere and then use the `void orientedBoundingBox.Box.Contain(Box3d)` (= the type of orientedBoundingBox.Box)  which then recalculates the main box to fit all these subboxes in. Not perfect ofcourse but should get pretty close I guess.

Comment: @Ruzihm just tested it with sphere models and just using all vertices (see update). Now that you mentioned it I'm interested in performance so maybe later I test a more complex model. But so far I'm pretty impressed ^^ Using this for meshColliders passing in the 8 vertices might have some pretty cool use cases for complex models

Comment: oh yeah that's the stuff

Comment: @Ruzihm Note that this is not giving the smallest bounding box either. See how in the second (spheres) illustration, after the second move, the box should be about the same as the first move, just reoriented, but instead if grows and the result is that the spheres occupy opposite corners of the bounding box, similar to the result from the first method in my own answer.

Comment: @XenoRo good catch! Didn't note that one .. There seem to be some cases when the box is not minimal perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of the box and then try to adapt it. It's easier to generate the box in this case. So points first, box later.

1. Find the two points most distant from eachother.

[image]

2. These will be two opposite corners of the box.
3. Calculate the direction/normal to the opposite point.
4. Calculate offset directions from that that will point to the missing points.

[image]

5. Generate the rest of the points of the box. Basically the directions you calculated by where they intersect the perpendicular paralel of the opposite point.
6. Generate the faces of the box based on its vertices.

[image]

---

I've illustrated for 2D here, but the only difference to 3D is a third angle, different angle offsets, and more vertices/faces to deal with.

---

## EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, this might not be a perfect solution. In cases where one or both extremities have multiple points that are close to, or at equal distance, from the opposing extremity, but separated laterally, this method will give you a decent ***approximation*** of the smallest bounding box, but will not give *the* smallest boudning box *possible*.

**Ruzihm's illustration:**

[image]

However, his illustration is a bit wrong, in that my solution is not axis-aligned. Here is what it would achieve, on the right, in red or orange, depending on which point is picked as the vertex:

[image]

---

## Better/Correct solution:

While looking for a solution that would give the mathematically perfect minimum bounding box, I've found [this other (C++) question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311306/how-to-find-an-arbitrarily-oriented-minimum-bounding-box-in-c). Right now I don't have the time to read through it all and replicate the solution here for Unity/C#, so I will only point to it. Maybe I or another contributor can edit-in a replication of that later.

Comment: Even with a broad interpretation of "two points most distant from eachother", this answer doesn't really work in every 2D situation: https://i.imgur.com/rOXMOs4.png

Comment: @Ruzihm Depends on if you want an axis aligned box or not.

Comment: @Draco18s OP clearly states that he wants it non-axis-aligned: `I also need to find the best possible orientation for the box`

Comment: @Ruzihm Nice catch! I didn't consider that scenario. Thanks!

Comment: @Ruzihm I've (somewhat) fixed the answer. Please consider a reevaluation. You got it a bit wrong in (apparently) thinking my initial solution was axis-aligned, but I understand the spirit of your criticism.

Comment: @Draco18s Same as the above.

Comment: How do you determine the direction of the orange lines? They have to be 90 degrees from each other but the diagonal doesn't have to be halfway between them. The smallest box might be a slightly tilted rectangle in the example case.

Comment: @Ruzihm The opposite is going to be opposite in both X and Y, if you think about it in aligned fashion. That is why there are 2 solutions if the distances are equal. One for each opposite point. The "excess" or "remainder" of the box always points towards closer points than the extremes, so they should always be covered by the bounding box. - I messed up the orange one, but u get the idea, I hope.

Comment: @Ruzihm Nevermind...The points are not equidistant in your illustration, so the red one would be the one solution.

Comment: So it seems like the direction of one of the sides is selected to touch one of the other input points but that can result in far off approximations https://imgur.com/a/apSTUJ2 (drawing on phone, sorry for even worse quality)

Comment: What I'm getting at is that there are infinitely many candidate rectangles that have opposite corners in two given positions

Comment: @Ruzihm Your drawing is right, and is the point I already acknoledged on the edit to the answer. (Maybe I didn't word that too clearly, but I am really busy rn so I'll try to improve later) --- As for infinite sollutions, I don't think so. They are derived from the extremity-points, so there should be two max orientations, and the width/height are derived from containment of the other points and/or length until perpendicular intersect with the opposite extremity. This is basically why the red box in your drawing is bigger than nescessary, and not the best solution. It's intrinsic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200746/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-xenoro).

Answer (score -2):

I was able to solve this by using OpenCV for Unity. I used the minAreaRect method, which calculates a fit bounding-box around the points in 2D (I projected them onto the X/Z plane first).

This method conveniently returned a rectangle, with a center point, angle and width / height. From here on it was quite easy to extend this to a 3D box.

Comment: you may want to add to the question that the bottom/top of the box must be parallel to the x/z plane, otherwise, this doesn't guarantee the smallest possible box and is not a valid answer (see [this example](https://imgur.com/a/Ici4ABa) with x-z projected circles in grey). Projecting up from the edges of the smallest bounding rectangle does not necessarily result in points in 3d space that are part of the smallest 3d box. - the x coordinates of the optimum box in this case extend beyond the 2d x coordiates for example

Comment: Not sure why I got so many downvotes. I see the point with z/x plane alignment, but the accepted answer has the opposite problem which is a z/x aligned box could be rotated so that is does not have the smallest volume possible. If you know the points are aligned to a plane, the extruded 2D solution works well