Axis aligned bounds around all children
A problem that keeps hauting me for years:
I have a GameObject "Master". Master has multiple children. Now I want to create a bounding box around Master that encapsulates all children. This is easily done with this code...
 var grpBounds = new Bounds() { center = master.transform.position };
 foreach (var meshrenderer in master.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>())
 {
     grpBounds.Encapsulate(meshrenderer.bounds);
 }
 boundingbox.localScale = grpBounds.size;
 boundingbox.position = grpBounds.center;

... The problem is that "Encapsultate()" draws bounds in global space. The previous code works fine, as long Master is aligned with global space. But if Master is rotated, the boudns will be still aligned with global space making the boundingbox way to big.
One solution for this is to align master globally, while bounds are calculated and then rotate everything back, with the bounds as child of master. This is a very awful solution though, and I'm sure there is a better one somewhere
This is how it looks when Master is not rotated:

This is how it looks when Master rotated:

This is how I want it to look when master is rotated:


This is a very awful solution though, and I'm sure there is a better one somewhere. Why? It is probably the best there is ... Alternatively there are some ways and libraries to calculate obb - see e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346819/finding-an-oriented-bounding-box-for-a-set-of-3d-points-in-unity

Note also that in general the bounds might be off for rotated meshes .. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711849/meshrenderer-has-wrong-bounds-when-rotated

If you rotated the bounds, then they wouldn't be axis-aligned (as your title suggests). The Bounds struct is supposed to represent an AABB, there's no rotation data.

@derHugo Forcing the rotatation of an object may trigger non related events like "OnTriggerEnter" or interact with physics based GameObjects in unindended ways. Many problems can be caused by that.

@KarlSupertramp I doubt this would happen if within the same frame you also move it back ... the physics are updated in the FixedUpdate so if you do your bounds update outside of that it should not affect physics afaik ... you could try

@derHugo Well - go ahead and try ;) This may work but is simply a workaround for a seemingly complicated mathproblem. We're investigating the calculation of rotated bounds now.

@KarlSupertramp well I just did and it has no effect whatsoever on collisions, triggers or the rigidbody velocities  .... I never said it is not a workaround ... but it is a very easy and stable one -> the best option there is if you don't want to wrap your head around it for long time ;) As said since you directly move it back in the same frame and even the same method execution no other system should be aware that it ever changed ... ok I found one exception so far: TrailRenderer
